# Form is automatically submitting when page is open

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form on landing page. And sending params to vuex `actions` with that. It working when I click the `submit` button, and push me the next page as it should. But there is a flaw. When I open the page, or refresh the page. It's submitting the params automatically, I don't know why?

**template**

```
<form class="flexbox" @submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
    <keyword-filter />
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <city-filter />
    <submit-btn />
</form>
```

**script**

```
created(){
    this.$store.dispatch("bridalApi", {
        input: this.formItems,
    });
},
methods: {
    submit(){
        this.$store.dispatch("bridalApi", {
            input:this.formItems
        })
        .then(this.$router.push('home'));
    },    
},
computed: {   
    formItems(){
        let paramObj = {
            keyword: this.$store.state.bridal.keyword,
            city: this.$store.state.bridal.city,
            price: this.$store.state.bridal.price,
            people: this.$store.state.bridal.people,
            rank: this.$store.state.bridal.rank,
            sort: this.$store.state.bridal.sort,
        }
        return paramObj;
    },
}
```

Additionally, it's sending the params when I refresh the page or enter the page(I don't want that). But it doesn't send me to next page? I am not very sure why it's submitting the params auto?

Comment: You are calling the `bridalApi` action inside your `created` hook. What are you expecting that to do? It seems at first glance to be the cause of the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is here

```
 created(){
    this.$store.dispatch("bridalApi", {
        input: this.formItems,
    });
},
```

The **created** hook can be used to run code after an instance is created, so whenever you reload the page, the component is being created and it is triggering that action from the store.
Check out https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram for more info.

Hope that helps!